# Calculate probability mass function (pmf)

Tags: probability

Consider the sample space $\Omega := \{1, 2,..., N\}$ for some $N \in \mathbb{N}$. Further, we have $\mathcal{A} := \mathcal{P}(\Omega)$.

Additionally, $\mathbb{P}(A) = \frac {|A|}{N}$ $(A \in \mathcal{A}$) is given.

I want to calculate the probability mass function $(p_w)_{w \in \Omega}$.

I know that $\mathbb{P}(A) = \sum_{w \in A} p_w$ but I don't know how to proceed at all.

Comment: Since $\mathcal{A}$ is the power set and contains all possible sets, how about you consider the case when $A$ is a single element of $\Omega$?

Comment: Isn't it simply the probability of one element of $\Omega$ = $\frac{1}{N}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is $p_w=\frac 1N$ for all $w \in \Omega$.